# Как исключить повторяющиеся значения при выводе python

Tags: python, bs4

**Код:**

```
import traceback
import requests
import dateparser
import pymysql
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    if r.ok: # 200  ## 403 404
        return r.text
    print(r.status_code)


def get_page_link(html): # <  Собираем главнные новости.
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    title =soup.find('h1',{'class':'roboto'}).text
    link_containers=soup.findAll('div',{'class':'cat_news_item'})

# < Этот цикл отбирает только ссылки на главные новости.
    counter = 0
    links_rcv = set()
    for link_container in link_containers:
        a_tag = link_container.find("a")
        # Если нашел
        if a_tag:
            link = a_tag.get("href")
            links_rcv.add(f'https://www.zakon.kz{link}')
        else:
            counter += 1
    return links_rcv


def get_context_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text


def get_context_data(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    mainblock = soup.find('div',{'class':'fullnews white_block'})  # < Получаем контекст.
    text_content = ''


    if mainblock is not None:  # < Если контекст не пуст, продолжаем разбор.
        item_title = mainblock.find('h1').text
        item_datetime = mainblock.find('span',{'class':'news_date'}).text
        item_text = mainblock.findAll('p')
        for text in item_text:
            text_content += f'{text.text}\n'
        item_datetime=dateparser.parse(item_datetime, date_formats=['%d %B %Y %H'])
    else:  # < Иначе получаем и разбираем контекст другого типа.
        mainblock = soup.find('div',{'class':'full_story'})
        item_title = soup.find('title').text
        item_datetime = soup.find('div',{'class':'news_date'})
        if not item_datetime:
            return "Error in datetime"
        else:
            item_datetime = item_datetime .text
        item_text = mainblock.findAll('p',{'class':'MsoNormal'})
        for text in item_text:
            text_content += f'{text.text}\n'
        item_datetime=dateparser.parse(item_datetime, date_formats=['%d %B %Y %H'])
    return (item_title,str(item_datetime),text_content)  # < Возвращаем результат, вне зависимости от типа страницы.


url = 'https://www.zakon.kz/news/'
links_rcv = get_page_link(get_html(url))

for i in links_rcv:
    result = get_context_data(get_context_html(i))
    if type(result) != "str":
        item_title = result[0]
        item_datetime = result[1]
        text_content = result[2]
        for item in result:
            try:
                print(item_title)
                # connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                #                              user='root',
                #                              password='',
                #                              db='news_portal',
                #                              charset='utf8',
                #                              autocommit=True)
                # cursor = connection.cursor()
                # sql = "insert into zakonkz (`item_link`,`item_title`, `item_datetime`, `text_content`) values (%s,%s,%s,%s)"
                # cursor.execute(sql,(str(link),str(title),str(datetime),str(content)))
            except:
                print(f'Ошибка на странице: {i}')
                print(traceback.format_exc())
    else:
        print(f"{result} {url}")
```

**Вывод кода:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос:** Как исключить повторяющиеся значение
**UPD:**Использовал функцию set().Повторяющиеся значение.Но это не принесло результатов.

Comment: Списком элементов из не повторяющихся значений является set(). Ищите в этом направлении...

Comment: Все гораздо проще. В цикле `for item in result:`  перебираются элементы `result`. В `result` - три элемента. Три раза происходит вывод `print(item_title)`. Проблема не в коде, а в логике.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простое условие перед добавлением ограничит ваш список от дублей:

```
my_list = list()
for item in values:
    if item not in my_list:
        my_list.append(item)
```

если вы там большим количеством элементов ворочаете - код заметно замедлится.

Comment: перед каким именно условием?

Comment: вы про что? мб перед добавлением в список?

Answer (score 0):

Заменить `links_rcv = []` в `get_page_link` на `links_rcv = set()`.

Comment: При выводе такая ошибка: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Администратор/PycharmProjects/Task/zakonkz/test.py", line 70, in <module>
    links_rcv = get_page_link(get_html(url))
  File "C:/Users/Администратор/PycharmProjects/Task/zakonkz/test.py", line 28, in get_page_link
    links_rcv.append(f'https://www.zakon.kz{link}')
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'append'
`

Comment: @r4khic если будете бездумно копировать то, что за вас другие написали, никогда не научитесь программировать. Почитайте про _множества_. Как минимум обнаружите, что у них вместо метода `append` используется метод `add`.

Comment: Хорошо.В следующий раз учту.Просто я чайник.

Comment: @r4khic все когда ими были.

Comment: Угу.Благодарю за понимание.

Comment: Проблема не решилась.Не подскажите с чего начать поиск ошибки.Я использовал функцию `set()` и добавил метод `add`.Но все равно при выводе данные повторяются

Comment: @r4khic проверьте содержимое `links_rcv` перед циклом `for i in links_rcv`. Возможно, на одну новость указывают разные ссылки.

Comment: Как именно проверить?  Функцией `type()` ? Или `isinstance()`

Comment: Функцией `print`.

Comment: Проверил.На выводе разные ссылки.Если указываются разные ссылки.Значит в этом проблема?

Comment: Множество устранило дубликаты ссылок, как и требовалось, но если разные ссылки указывают в одно место, то с этим оно вам не поможет. Придётся изменять алгоритм в цикле, формировать там ещё одно множество - уже из заголовков, а не ссылок, а потом в отдельном цикле работать с ним.

Comment: Можно пожалуйста пример?

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял, в `result` хранится 3 элемента - `item_title, item_datetime, text_content`

В этом цикле

```py
item_title = result[0]
item_datetime = result[1]
text_content = result[2]
for item in result:
    try:
        print(item_title)
        # connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
        #                              user='root',
        #                              password='',
        #                              db='news_portal',
        #                              charset='utf8',
        #                              autocommit=True)
        # cursor = connection.cursor()
        # sql = "insert into zakonkz (`item_link`,`item_title`, `item_datetime`, `text_content`) values (%s,%s,%s,%s)"
        # cursor.execute(sql,(str(link),str(title),str(datetime),str(content)))
    except:
        print(f'Ошибка на странице: {i}')
        print(traceback.format_exc())
```

для одного и того же `result` вы три раза выводите `item_title` -> вот вам и повторение.

UPD: из-за этого у вас будет три раза записываться одно и тоже в базу